# MongoDB Database connection error - Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, docker

I have built a client-server application and I use MongoDB as my database.

I wanted to use docker-compose, but got after `docker-compose` up Database connection error

My application structure looks like this

- dist

  - client
  - server
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- package.json

**Dockerfile**

```
# Create image based on the official Node 10 image from dockerhub
FROM node:10

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package*.json /app/

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /app/

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 8000

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

**docker.compose.yml**

```
version: '2' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  angular: # name of the first service
    build: ./ # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # specify port forwarding
    links:
      - database # link this service to the database service
  database: # name of the third service
    restart: always
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forewarding
```

**database**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const server = 'database:27017'; // REPLACE WITH YOUR DB SERVER
const database = 'twitter';

export class Database {
  constructor() {}

  static connect() {
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`, {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Database connection successful');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Database connection error');
      });
  }
}
```

Here I set my host to **databse** instead of **localhost**

**server**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import { Routes } from './routes/twitter';


class App {

  public app: express.Application;
  public route: Routes = new Routes();

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.route.routes(this.app);
  }

  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    if (this.app.get('env') === 'production') {
      // loading the angular client folder or application
      this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client')));
    }
  }

}

export default new App().app;
```

**Commands**

> docker-compose up

**package.json script**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server:run\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
    "server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon dist/server/server.js\" ",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-path=dist/client && npm run server:build",
    "server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
    "copyfiles": "cp -R ai dist/server/routes",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/server.js"
  },
```

The application is running under localhost:8000
The client site is working fine but can not access to the backend due the databse connection error

In the browser I am getting following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

On my console I have just

> angular_1   |  angular_1   | > proto@0.0.0 start:prod /app angular_1
>   | > NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/server.js angular_1   | 
>   angular_1   | Express server listening on port 8000 angular_1   |
>   Database connection error

Comment: Can you post the error

Comment: Please see above I have added it there

Comment: What is the actual error from the catch?

Comment: Ok, I can now connect the database. But I am getting Cannot get /home (route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your database URL is not correct, because `const server = 'database:27017';` is not resolved from inside of your containers. 
When you use docker-compose, the containers are builded on a default network, so you can reach services from container_name: if your mongo container is called "mongo_db", in your service that have to communicate with db, the url `const server = 'mongo_db:27017';`.

PS. However, i always recommend to use ENV variables, so you can setup these things from the outside,